# OSGI Configuration

Tags: aem, sap-commerce-cloud

I need to configure the Hybris version in "Day CQ Commerce Hybris Configuration" in configMgr console. In the drop-down i could see only three values which will be specified in the java class file like @Property by giving the label and value. Where i can see this file/ configuration(Day CQ Commerce Hybris Configuration) in author side .

[aem console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHx6L.png)

I don't have any code base. I just started with Author instance using the jar(aem-author-6.1.0). Where i can see the configuration to change/add new values ?

Can anyone help me on this.

Thanks !

[Hybris Configuration_New](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h05AN.png) :

Answer (score 3):

It's not necessary to modify the `OSGi` java class to include new entries to the drop down. You can just overlay the corresponding run mode configs and add your new entries there.

In your case, you should be able to find the OOTB run mode config for 'Hybris Configuration' in `/libs/commerce/config.author/com.adobe.cq.commerce.hybris.common.DefaultHybrisConfigurationService`

[image]

Overlay the above config by creating the below node tree `/apps/commerce/config.author/com.adobe.cq.commerce.hybris.common.DefaultHybrisConfigurationService.config`.

[image]

Easiest way to create this node tree - Just update any of the config values of the OOTB config from 'system/console/configMgr' and hit save. This will automatically create this node tree for you. Now just add/modify the entries in the `nt:file` node. `OSGi` will pick these entries instead of the one's from `/libs`

Comment: Tried the same, but not able to add values.PFA(Hybris_Config_New)

These component will be installed once we install cq hybris plugin and now im not able to select the version which i'm trying to connect. So, i need to add new values say 6.6

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of the new run mode config. Ensure this is not getting overwritten when you are installing the hybris plugin.